# How to take advantage of shrinking in a complex case

Tags: f#, fscheck

I'm just getting started with FsCheck. I need to generate some test data, here `TestData` represents the input to my test:

```
type Interval = { Start : DateTime; End : DateTime }
type Frob = { Interval : Interval; MustFrob : bool }

type TestData = { Intervals: Interval[]; Frob : Frob option }
```

My generation code looks like:

```
let generator = gen {
    let! startTime = Arb.Default.DateTime().Generator
    return! Gen.sized(fun size -> gen {
         let intervalDurations = Gen.listOfLength size myOwnSuperDurationGenerator
         let intervals = 
              // blabla using startTime and intervalDurations

         let! maybeFrob = Arb.Default.Option<Frob>().Generator
         let adjustedFrob = maybeFrob |> Option.map(fun f ->
              { f with Interval = // mess with the interval }
         return { Intervals = intervals; Frob = adjustedFrob }         
    }
}
```

So, this works, but I don't like the calls to `Arb.Default.Blabla().Generator` because I can't pass them the size parameter so my tests don't take advantage of shrinking there. For instance shrinking the `Frob option` to `None`, or choosing a simpler `startTime`. Is there a way to propagate that size parameter when generating single values like this? - also thanks for pointing out any egregious beginner mistakes, I'm really just trying to figure out how to use this API.

Comment: I don't think that there's an easy way to get a shrinker out of a complex generator, but you can build your own from existing shrinkers. This question seems reminiscent of this recent question on GitHub: https://github.com/fscheck/FsCheck/issues/298 If you can supply an [MCV](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I'll be happy to suggest concrete code, but ATM the OP code doesn't compile.